# Why doesn't this footer expand completely to the sides?

Tags: html, css, footer

I am designing a template for my school's website and require some help. All was going great until I got to the footer. I have noticed that everything **but** the top navigation is unable to expand completely to the sides of the screen. This is really frustrating as I am trying to fill the footer to the same width as the navigation.

[For your convenience, I have uploaded a copy of the template here.](http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/) I believe that it is related to the [css](http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/style.css) but I have tried every possible value I can think of to no effect.

Please help if you can.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.victoriaparkci.com%2Ftpl2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have an 8px margin on the body element. In your css, try this

```
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That's a good snippet to include in every project btw.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe that it was that simple :D

Answer (score 1):

Add Margin:0px to the body{ tag in the CSS

This will fix it:

```
body{
    background: #fbe2a9 url(images/body-bg.jpg) repeat-x  top;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers, by default, give the `body` tag a margin. So, all you need to do is set that to 0:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

The reason why the top navigation appears how you want it to, is because you're setting the `position` to `fixed` and "gluing" it to the top left of the screen (0, 0) with a width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0` to the body tag

Answer (score 0):

Well to start, you are doing clear:both and float:left, when you only need clear:both. 
Then add the following to #footer_wrapper:

```
#footer_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left:-7px;
}
```